# Adding to Oracle DB through Windows Form

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am writing a small Windows Application and I am tasked with allowing a user of the system to add, delete, update and view records via stored procedures. I am able to view and update existing records but I cannot add records correctly. The add function adds the PartNo and Quantity but It does not add the PartName or Manufacturer. They appear as zero when i refresh the table after I add a new part. This is my Add sub_routine below and my stored procedure too. I am using Oracle SQL Developer and Visual Studio 2015. Is my syntax correct or am I missing something that is making the add method exclude the PartName and Manufacturer.

// Sub routine that adds record to PARTS table

```
Private Sub addPart_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles addPart.Click

        Dim cmd As New OracleCommand("Garage.ADDPART", Form1.Connect())
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@PARTNO", Val(txtAddPartNo.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@PARTNAME", Val(txtAddPartName.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@MANUFACTURER", Val(txtAddManufacturer.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@QUANTITY", Val(txtAddQuantity.Text))
        Try
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("Record Added")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

// ADDPART Stored Procedure

```
create or replace procedure ADDPART(
new_partno PART.PARTNO%type,
new_partname PART.PARTNAME%type,
new_manufacturer PART.MANUFACTURER%type,
new_quantity PART.QUANTITY%type)
as
begin insert into PART
(PARTNO, PARTNAME, MANUFACTURER, QUANTITY)
values
(new_partno, new_partname, new_manufacturer, new_quantity);
Commit;
exception
when dup_val_on_index then
raise_application_error(-20001, 'Product already exists');
when others then
raise_application_error(-20011, sqlerrm);
END ADDPART;
```

Comment: Given the datatypes described in the VB call to the stored procedure I assume that they are all numeric as you are converting them from text to number using the `val()` function.  My guess is that the text in partname and manufacturer is being converted to zero.  Can you post the part create table script?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean

Comment: In your code you are converting the text in each of the textboxes to numeric using the `val()` function, it's obvious in your question that the text in `txtAddPartName.Text` and `txtAddManufacturer.Text` are being converted to number.  I'm curious to see if the part table columns are number or varchar2 columns, so I asked if you could post your table script for the part table.  I suspect that the data in those textboxes are not numeric and are converting to zero and I'm looking for evidence of that.

Comment: Partname and manufacture are varchar2 data types in my table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that your table columns for partname and manufacturer are varchar2, change your procedure call to the stored procedure to this:

```
Private Sub addPart_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles addPart.Click

    Dim cmd As New OracleCommand("Garage.ADDPART", Form1.Connect())
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@PARTNO", Val(txtAddPartNo.Text))
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@PARTNAME", txtAddPartName.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@MANUFACTURER", txtAddManufacturer.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@QUANTITY", Val(txtAddQuantity.Text))
    Try
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("Record Added")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Remove the `val()` function from `txtAddPartName.text` and `txtAddManufacturer.text`.

Comment: It's working perfectly. Thank You Very Much. I will accept your answer now and mark this as solved.